# Why Does the program write dna without whitespace

Tags: c

I have two function one for printing genes and the other one for creating dna from a string. The latter function takes something like "ATCGGGAAC" and create a result whose type is char** like result={{"ATC"},{"GGG",},{"AAC"}}; but when print the result ı get ATCGGGAAC , My aim is to print like ATC GGG AAC what is wrong with my functions ?
firstly print function ;

To be more clear ;

> this function should take dnaString (char*) and create a DNA (char**).
> When dnaString is NULL, return NULL and do nothing. Otherwise make
> sure that each part of the DNA has 3 nucleotides. See DNA/RNA
> STRUCTURE section above to understand the structure.
>
> dnaString: AGCTTGAATCGGCCTTAATGTTTT
> DNA: AGC TTG AAT CGG CCT TAA TGT TTT

```
/* prints DNA or RNA */
void printGenes(char** dnaOrRna) {
    int i = 0;

    if (dnaOrRna == NULL) {
        printf("No genes found.\n");
    }
    else {
        /* while current gene is not NULL, print gene */
        while (dnaOrRna[i] != NULL) {
            /* if next gene is not NULL, print with space */
            if (dnaOrRna[i+1] != NULL) {
                printf("%s ", dnaOrRna[i]);
            }
            /* if next gene is NULL, print without space */
            else {
                printf("%s", dnaOrRna[i]);
            }

            i++;
        }
        /* print additional newline */
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

secondly my function which generates a dna from a string;

```
char** generateDNA(char *dnaString)
{   if(*dnaString)
    {  int i;
       char *temp;
       char **result;
       int size=getStringLength(dnaString);
       temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
       temp=dnaString;
       result=(char**)malloc(1+size/3);
       for(i=0;i<size/3;i++)
       {
        result[i]=temp;
        temp=temp+3;
        i++;
       }
        result[size/3]=NULL;
        printGenes(result);
       
       return result;
    }
    else 
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp=dnaString;` writes over away the pointer just allocated with `temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);`.  Certainly a problem.

Comment: `char **result; ... result=(char**)malloc(1+size/3);` looks wrong too.  I'd expect the size given to allocate would include the size of `*result`, a pointer.  It is unclear to me what `generateDNA()` is really trying to do.

Comment: @chux  I edited  the context

Comment: Usually the logic to add space is "have I already printed something, if so add a space before this output". That prevents a read beyond the buffer. It will also remove the (almost) duplicate print statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, your `printGenes` function looks OK. `generateDNA` has a couple of pointer related issues though. Let me see if I can draw it out:

Keep in mind that in C, all strings end in '\0' and any string related functions will continue until it finds that NULL.

At the beginning of `generateDNA`, we have a single string:

```
 dnaString
 |
 v
"ATCGGGAAC\0"
```

You then allocate a small string for `temp`:

```
 dnaString
 |
 v
"ATCGGGAAC\0"

 temp
 |
 v
"xxx" // uninitialized garbage data
```

You then point `temp` to the same string as `dnaString`. Note that you have now leaked 3 bytes of memory, since nothing points to the original `temp` buffer anymore:

```
 dnaString
 |
 v
"ATCGGGAAC\0"
 ^
 |
 temp

"xxx" // uninitialized garbage data (leaked)
```

You then allocate an array, and populate it:

[0]

```
dnaString
 |
 v
"ATCGGGAAC\0"
 ^  ^
 |  |
 |  temp
 result[0]

"xxx" // uninitialized garbage data (leaked)
```

[1]

```
dnaString
 |
 v
"ATCGGGAAC\0"
 ^  ^  ^
 |  |  |
 |  |  temp
 |  result[1]
 result[0]

"xxx" // uninitialized garbage data (leaked)
```

And so on.

Now, this means that `result[0]` points to the string `"ATCGGGAAC\0"`, and `result[1]` points to the string `"GGGAAC\0"`, which is almost certainly not what you intended.

You probably want something like this instead (untested), where each element in result[] points to its own string:

```
int size=getStringLength(dnaString);
temp=dnaString;
result=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (1+size/3));
for(i=0;i<size/3;i++) {
    result[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    memcpy(result[i], temp, 3);
    result[i][3] = NULL;
    temp += 3;
}
result[size/3]=NULL;
printGenes(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your printing function is correct, but I see a few problems elsewhere in your code.

First, you are incrementing `i` twice:

```
for(i=0; i<size/3; i++)
   {
   ...
   i++;
   }
```

Second (and I think this is the main issue related to your question), when you assign `result[i]`, you aren't terminating the string.  So, you end up with e.g. from input of "AAACCCGGGTTT":

```
result[0] AAACCCGGGTTT
result[1] CCCGGGTTT
result[2] GGGTTT
result[3] TTT
```

I believe you are seeing the 'no-spaces' version of the DNA string when you print `result[0]`.  When I removed the redundant `i++` and ran your code, I received this output:

```
AAACCCGGGTTT CCCGGGTTT GGGTTT TTT  ....
```

That "...." is a bunch of additional bytes, printed because `result[3]` isn't terminated either.

Notice that the output *does* have spaces between e.g., AAACCCGGGTTT and CCCGGGTTT, etc.  So, all you need to do is null-terminate each element of `result[]`, and you'll your printing function will produce the output you expect.